# Как поменять синий цвет и (интервал минуты 15m) в input time и д

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

<input type = 'time'/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]> .

Comment: По моему никак :) по крайней мере средствами css - никак

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato наверное ты прав

Answer (score 1):

Удачи ^-^

```js
const time = document.querySelector(".time");

let createTimeHour = document.createElement("div");
createTimeHour.className = "time-hour";
createTimeHour.innerHTML = "--";
let createTimeMins = document.createElement("div");
createTimeMins.className = "time-mins";
createTimeMins.innerHTML = "--";

time.append(createTimeHour, time.children[time.children.length - 1]);
time.append(":", time.children[time.children.length - 1]);
time.append(createTimeMins, time.children[time.children.length - 1]);

const selectHourValue = document.querySelector(".time-hour");
const selectMinsValue = document.querySelector(".time-mins");

let createTimeSelect = document.createElement("div");
createTimeSelect.className = "select-time";

let createTimeSelectHour = document.createElement("div");
createTimeSelectHour.className = "select-time-hour";

for (let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
  let createHourBlock = document.createElement("div");
  createHourBlock.className = "select-time-hour-value";
  createHourBlock.innerHTML = i;
  createHourBlock.addEventListener("click", selectHour);
  createTimeSelectHour.append(createHourBlock);
}
createTimeSelect.append(createTimeSelectHour);

let createTimeSelectMins = document.createElement("div");
createTimeSelectMins.className = "select-time-mins";

//Тут поменять i += 5 на i += 15 что-бы интервал был 15 мин
for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i += 5) {
  let createMinsBlock = document.createElement("div");
  createMinsBlock.className = "select-time-mins-value";
  createMinsBlock.innerHTML = i;
  createMinsBlock.addEventListener("click", selectMins);
  createTimeSelectMins.append(createMinsBlock);
}
createTimeSelect.append(createTimeSelectMins);

time.append(createTimeSelect);

time.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.parentElement.children[3].classList.toggle("select-time-active");
})

function selectHour() {
  let hourValue = this.innerHTML > 9 ? this.innerHTML : "0" + this.innerHTML;
  selectHourValue.innerHTML = hourValue;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.parentElement.children.length; i++) {
    this.parentElement.children[i].classList.remove("select-time-hour-active");
  }
  this.classList.add("select-time-hour-active");
}

function selectMins() {
  let minsValue = this.innerHTML > 9 ? this.innerHTML : "0" + this.innerHTML;
  selectMinsValue.innerHTML = minsValue;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.parentElement.children.length; i++) {
    this.parentElement.children[i].classList.remove("select-time-mins-active");
  }
  this.classList.add("select-time-mins-active");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.time {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px .1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.time div {
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.time img {
  height: 90%;
}

.select-time {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(100% + 4px);
  left: 0;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.select-time-hour,
.select-time-mins {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.select-time-hour div,
.select-time-mins div {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.select-time-hour-active,
.select-time-mins-active,
.select-time-hour div:hover,
.select-time-mins div:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.select-time-hour::-webkit-scrollbar,
.select-time-mins::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.select-time-active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency-systems-regular/32/000000/clock--v3.png" />
</div>
```